# Simple: convertAndSendToUser Where do I get a username?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

In Spring Boot (Websockets)

I just saw this example:

```
messaging.convertAndSendToUser( username, "/queue/notifications",
                       new Notification("You just got mentioned!"));
```

Where does the guy get a username from? I can't find any mention about where to get that username...

Comment: The username is the the value that the users provide when they connect to your websocket app. You can check the connected users by injecting `SimpUserRegistry` and calling `getUsers()` method. Afterwards find the username of one of the users and try sending the message to it.

Comment: @Edd Can you provide a STOMP SockJS example of connection with username?

Comment: Btw @Edd `SimpUserRegistry` has empty set of `SimpUser`s even though I am connected to it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This answer is written based on this application: https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-messaging-stomp-websocket

In order to register a user, you must first create an object that will represent it, for example:

```
public final class User implements Principal {

    private final String name;

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Then you'll need a way to create these `User` objects. One way of doing it is when `SockJS` sends you the connect message headers. In order to do so, you need to intercept the connect message. You can do that by creating our your interceptor, for example:

```
public class UserInterceptor extends ChannelInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {

        StompHeaderAccessor accessor =
                MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);

        if (StompCommand.CONNECT.equals(accessor.getCommand())) {
            Object raw = message
                    .getHeaders()
                    .get(SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.NATIVE_HEADERS);

            if (raw instanceof Map) {
                Object name = ((Map) raw).get("name");

                if (name instanceof LinkedList) {
                    accessor.setUser(new User(((LinkedList) name).get(0).toString()));
                }
            }
        }
        return message;
    }
}
```

Once you have that, you must also register this `UserInterceptor`. I'm guessing somewhere in your application you have defined a configuration `AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer` class. In this class you can register your user interceptor by overriding `configureClientInboundChannel` method. You can do it like this:

```
@Override
public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
    registration.setInterceptors(new UserInterceptor());
}
```

And then finally, when your clients connect, they'll have to provide their usernames:

```
stompClient.connect({
    name: 'test' // Username!
}, function () {
    console.log('connected');
});
```

After you have all this setup, `simpUserRegistry.getUsers()` will return a list of users and you'll be able to use `convertAndSendToUser` method:

```
messaging.convertAndSendToUser("test", ..., ...);
```

**Edit**

Testing this out a bit further, when subscribing, you'll have to prefix your topics with `/user` as `SimpMessagingTemplate` uses this as a default prefix, for example:

```
stompClient.subscribe('/user/...', ...);
```

Also I had made a mistake in `UserInterceptor` and corrected it (name parsing part).

Comment: Do I also have to prefix every MessageMapping and SendTo annotations? @Edd

Comment: PERFECT!!! This works even without `/user/` default prefix... THANK YOU ( I would upvote but I have reputation less than 15 )

Comment: Oh I think you're right I need to prefix it with `/user/` because it's not working right now

Comment: Is this still the *best* implementation in 2019?